# How can I determine what the audio file extension probably is (Chrome, Android)?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, audio, format

When reading audio files from web pages in Chrome on Android (latest version, both) it happens that the file extension is missing from the file name in the `<input type="file" accept="audio/*">`.

I need to determine if it really is an audio file and what extension it then could have.

Is there any easy way to do that?

---

EDIT: If I look with for example Google's Files the file has a correct file extension. But there is some bug in Chrome on Android that I'm trying to work around at the moment. (If that doesn't take too long time I will get time to file another bug report.)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the type of the file from filelist of the `input`

```js
let fileinput = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
let button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
  if(fileinput.files !== null){
    if(/audio\/*/.test(fileinput.files[0]['type']) === true){
    let getExtension = fileinput.files[0]['name'].split('.');
      alert(`This is an audio file and the extension for this file is ${getExtension[getExtension.length - 1]}`)
    }else{
    alert('Nope')
}
  }else{
  alert('Pick a file')
  }

})
```

```html
<input type="file" multiple="false" accept="audio/*">

<button>Is this a Audio File ?</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I said the extension is not there. It is empty.